# Laravel auth middleware throws illegal offset type exception

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, middleware, laravel-7

I recently upgraded my project to Laravel 7 from 5.6.
The upgrade itself worked out without any issues and the project is in a usable state. Now I want to add authentication to the project so that API Users can register and login. 
Registering a user and login works, but as soon as I use the "auth" middleware I get this  [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlis4.png) .

When setting a breakpoint on line 68 of the AuthManager.php and going through the whole process step by step with xDebug it turns out that the guard($name) gets called with $name set to a HttpRequest. Which is the reason for the illegal offset exception, since the resolve() method only accepts strings as parameter.

I didn't modifiy the AuthManager.php

my routes in web.php:

```
 //Routes for logged in users
 //When one of these routes gets called the exception shown above gets thrown
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/dev/api/developer/home', 'ApiUserController@index')->name('developer.home');
    Route::post('/dev/api/developer/requestKey', 'ApiUserController@requestKey')->name('developer.requestKey');
});
```

my auth.php:

```
<?php

return [
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
];
```

my Http\Kernel.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,

];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol::class
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'localization' => \App\Http\Middleware\localization::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];}
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? I'd appreciate any help. If you need any additional information please tell me. Thank you all in advance

Comment: did you solve this? this is happening to me as well

Comment: Hi caro, no I couldn't solve this. My Project wasn't huge enough to the point where I couldn't redo it in a new laravel Version. I'm pretty sure the reason for this behaviour for me was the update process. I must have taken the wrong turn somewhere down the road. Good Luck maybe you'll find a fix!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and no hope for help. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should set a default guard

```
'defaults' => [
   'guard'     => 'web',
   'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I accidentally removed the default part when i formatted the question. The default guard is set in the auth.php

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. After some searching I found the problem:

In `App\Http\Kernal.php` is an array in the bottom of the file.

[image]

For some reason the keys `auth` and `auth.basis` had a `capital letter` like this:

[image]

If you put it in lowercase it will work again (atleast in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 2 years old, I got the same issue in laravel 9 i could not fix it , but i found a workout

Create a new api or web route, like you usually do and call the logout method

```
Auth::logout()
```

And dont forget to call on the top

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

I did this and it worked fine for me.